# Xcode6: Playground not working. All options grayed out on Product menu

Tags: xcode6

OS X 10.9.3 iMac

Installed Xcode 6 beta today and I am immediately stuck.

Following an apparently successful install, without errors, I have done nothing more than:

1. Clicked the "Xcode 6 Beta" icon to run
2. On the "Welcome to Xcode" screen, clic ked "Get started with a playground"
3. Created a new Playground file
4. Error thrown. "Error running playground. Failed to prepare for communication with playground"
5. All options under the "Product" menu are grayed out: Run, build, etc.

Anyone else, or is it just me?

Tyvm
Keith

Comment: Xcode 6 is still under NDA. It would be more appropriate to post this in Apple Dev Forum.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Try closing Playground or Xcode 6(Same thing) and reopen. This seemed to fix my problem.